# Find a basis in which matrix will be diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

Let $F=        \begin{bmatrix}
        -1 & -2 & 2 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$ is a matrix of a linear transformation $f:\mathbb{R^3}\rightarrow \mathbb{R^3}$ in standard basis. Find a basis in which $F$ will be diagonal matrix.

Matrix $F$ is diagonalizable $\Rightarrow J=\begin{bmatrix}
        -1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$ and a basis in which $F$ is diagonal are column vectors of $J$.

Is this correct?

Comment: $J$ is correct, but for the basis it is false. Why do you say that? You have to find a basis of eigenvectors.

Comment: the new basis are found as the eigenvectors of $F$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write $F = Q\Lambda Q^{-1}$, where $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix, and Q contains the eigenvectors as its columns. Then Q is a set of basis for which F is a scaling transformation. To see this, $Q\Lambda Q^{-1}$ is applied from right to left, and means:

$Q^{-1}$ maps any vector in the original space into vector represented by basis Q

$\Lambda$ performs a scaling (diagonal) transformation

$Q$ maps the vector represented in basis $Q$ back to original space.

So if you think about this decomposition of transformation mean, you can see why Q is the basis for which the transformation F can be represented by a diagonal matrix

Answer (score 0):

To calcuate the eigenvalues consider the matrix $T=    \begin{bmatrix}
        -1-t & -2 & 2 \\
        0 & 1-t & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1-t \\
        \end{bmatrix}$

The characteristic polynomial is  $(1-t)^2(-1-t) $  . The eigenvalues are $1,1,-1$. Now consider the matrix $T-tI $ before with $t=1$ and with $t=-1$ and consider the $\ker T-tI $ to find the eigenvectors